# Drawing shapes in textboxes

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

Is it possible to draw a shape in a textbox(not rich)?

I tried the below, but nothing seems to happen.

```
Protected Overloads Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal pevent As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    pevent.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, pevent.ClipRectangle)
End Sub
```

The future hope is to make a textbox with a watermark type image on the side.

Comment: You can't make it work with TextBox.  There's a project that hacks around the limitations (doesn't actually use a TextBox), can't really recommend it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/alphablendtextbox.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you put a breakpoint in the debugger do you reach this line? I believe you need to use `SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)` before your control will call `OnPaintBackground`.</strike>

You may want to look at this SO answer about custom backgrounds in WinForm textboxes: [Can a background image be set on a Winforms TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360301/can-a-background-image-be-set-on-a-winforms-textbox)

The short answer, is it looks like this is not easily possible due.

You may want to look at [this article](http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/), as it offers some interesting approaches to custom drawn text box controls.