# best way to create a fancy log

Tags: c#, logging

I have a 'log' in my application. Currently I'm using richtextbox control to display colored text. The problem I want to have a simple animation from background images in the background. According to this answer: [Can a background image be set on a Winforms TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360301/can-a-background-image-be-set-on-a-winforms-textbox) it's not recommended. I could use datagridview for log, but it flickers when new items are added and it makes it look unstable and ugly. What would be a good way on winforms to display colored text in log and have a background image? Thanks!

Comment: Do you ***absolutely need*** a background image for your log?

Comment: What does this have to do with logging?

Comment: @Nolanar it would be perfect because I want to make a really cool 'broken console' effect, of course I don't need it ;)

Comment: @AlexG Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't Logging a verb of Log?

Comment: @Kristian What he means is that this is a question about putting a background image on a text container and is not a question about logging - it's a roundabout way of saying that you should not have used the `logging` tag and should edit the question to remove it.

Comment: It is - but this question does not seem to be about logging. It is about displaying a background behind some text. Is that right, or is there some part of the requirement that is specific to logging?

Comment: @Kristian I think the point is that it is only incidental that you are using it to display a log, so `logging` isn't relevant as a tag for the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is easy and looks at least decent your best bet is probably to use WPF Interop (ElementHost) and build the control in WPF.  Winforms constrols are a real headache for this type of application.

The WPF TextBox already supports a background image and renders it well.

In your WinForms Project :  Right-click, "Add" -->  "New Item..."

Select "WPF" -->  "UserControl".

Drag a WPF TextBox onto the control, set up background image as you like, etc.

In your Winforms form --> "WPF Interoperability" (in Tools pane) --> drag "ElementHost" to your form.

Set the "Selected Host Content" to your new WPF user control.

Job done.