# UserPainted textbox gets white text

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am trying to make a textbox with a watermark text on winforms. I have created a custom textbox (inherited from `TextBox`) and am Painting the watermark.
The problem is that the text inside the textbox gets white (disappears) as soon as I enter the textbox with my mouse.

I think it is because the textbox gets invalidated when the mouse enters the region without calling the paint method.

Any ideas how to fix this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: for gods sake ,,can you post the code,,,the user defined

Comment: There is no code to post, as the ONLY thing I've done so far is to SetStyle UserPaint. Thanks for your constructive answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a background image be set on a Winforms TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360301/can-a-background-image-be-set-on-a-winforms-textbox)

Comment: Even if the question you posted has nothing to do with mine, it answered my question. Thanks.