# Change the TextBox highlight color when a user selects text?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been looking for the way to change the textbox highlight color when a user select text. Windows uses blue as default color. For example, on Microsoft Outlook, when you write a mail and select (highlight) text, the back color is gray.

[image: Selected text in Outlook]

[image: TextBox selected text by user]

Everybody said that I need to override onPaint method but i don't know how exactly to do that. The RichTextbox selectedbackground color is not the solution because it changes the color for the text, not when the user selects it.

Comment: you need to understand the the following for example 
`int length = richTextBox.TextLength
richTextBox.SelectionStart = length;
richTextBox.SelectionLength = yourstring.Length;
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;` something like that

Comment: That makes a background color on the text, but when user select it, it still in blue.

I'm looking to change the rectangle color that is drawn when a user select a text with his mouse or with Shift key.

Comment: do a google search I have seen several examples online about highlighting selection text

Comment: @MethodMan I googled and nothing to find. Can you give some link?

Comment: I found some related articles [some examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/TextBoxState/-/php-textboxstate-class-examples.html).
And [OnPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330186/textbox-drawn-in-wm-paint-flickers-on-mouse-enter-leave)
Maybe it helps.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the rtb. If you want a simple single line without draging and droping or moving selections and other fancy staff with just numbers or text it is not so difficult. But if you want the whole deal that is a looot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option, you can rely on an [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) Windows Forms control to host a WPF `TextBox` control. Then for the WPF `TextBox` control, set `SelectionBrush` and `SelectionOpacity`.

**Example**

In the following example I've created a Windows Forms `UserControl` containing an `ElementHost` to host a WPF `TextBox` control. Then for the WPF `TextBox` control, set `SelectionBrush` and `SelectionOpacity`.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Media;
public class MyWPFTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    private ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost();
    private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    public MyWPFTextBox()
    {
        textBox.SelectionBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        textBox.SelectionOpacity = 0.5;
        textBox.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
        textBox.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        elementHost.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        elementHost.Name = "elementHost";
        elementHost.Child = textBox;
        textBox.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        Controls.Add(elementHost);
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return textBox.Text; }
        set { textBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

*Referenced Assemblies*

Here are required referenced assemblies: `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework`, `WindowsBase`, `WindowsFormsIntegration`.

Comment: +1 That's exactly the only solution I thought of. But I also may be wrong. Note for anyone who would use this solution, it only works with framework >= 4.0. Still looking for other answers that may provide better native Winforms solutions. Also, the `SelectionBrush` in WPF isn't too advanced (i.e no fore/back colors specifying. Only Opacity. But still a good solution). Though thanks for your answer!

Comment: @XStylish You're welcome. As far as I know there is no native support for changing selection highlight color of native text box independent from windows theme.

Comment: Be aware that `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` has no property `SelectionBrush`. That is only in `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse the `textBox` in the answer is a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`.

Comment: This seems a nice solution. More framework native and affordable, maybe this will work with Mono.

Comment: @TannerOrnelas You can also extend the class by adding more properties and events.

Answer (score 2):

Hi here is the code to change the selection colour just keep in mind that you will have to store the current colour and then once you've changed the colour and your application closes you would need to restore it because this changes the colour of the whole computer not just for the current process.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetSysColors(int cElements, int[] lpaElements, uint[] lpaRgbValues);


    void ChangeSelectColour(Color color)
    {
        const int COLOR_HIGHLIGHT = 13;
        const int COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT = 14;
        // You will have to set the HighlightText colour if you want to change that as well.


        //array of elements to change
        int[] elements = { COLOR_HIGHLIGHT };


        List<uint> colours = new List<uint>();
        colours.Add((uint)ColorTranslator.ToWin32(color));

        //set the desktop color using p/invoke
        SetSysColors(elements.Length, elements, colours.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: This seems an approach but going to the OS is a little risky.

Comment: It is not risky. But it changes the settings for ALL running applications including Windows Explorer. This is surely not what the user expects. It is a pity that Microsoft did not implement a function which does the same as SetSysColors, but only for the current application.