# Changing the highlight color of a TextBox's selected text

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, wndproc, onpaint

I've been searching for a way to do this in `WinForms` for quite a while, anybody know of a way to change its default from `SystemColors.Highlight` to something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34666064/1997232) already (simply to link questions together).

Comment: I'm in no way familiar with winforms, but what I'm getting is that you have to force the change from within the app and change the system default highlight color. [SetSysColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940(v=vs.85).aspx). There was stress on making sure you set it back to default once application closes.

Comment: `SetSysColors function sends a WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE message to all windows to inform them of the change in color` eeeeeh, no thanks