# How do I highlight text selection in a Textbox in a C# Winforms program?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `windows forms application` that gets an ID, or more, in a `richtextbox` and validates it. If the ID or IDs is invalid will be highlighted in yellow.

```
richTextBoxCode_.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

What I want is to switch the `richtextbox` with a `textbox` but seems `textbox` doesn't have the `SelectionBackColor` . Is there any way to do this in a `textbox`?
Thanks!

Comment: Basically this is defined by system settings and can't be changed. But if you need this very much you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666064/change-the-textbox-highlight-color-when-a-user-selects-text

Comment: txtTextBox.ForeColoe = Color.Yellow; ?

Comment: txtTextBox.ForeColor changes the fore color of the text. What I need is to keep same text color but highlight the background of the selection. @Oswald

Comment: So then i do agree with demonplus @BogdanSorin

Comment: I've answered [almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48222621/how-to-highlight-the-wrapped-text-in-a-control-using-the-graphics/48257170#48257170) a few days ago. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for help, thumb up!