# Reverse winforms treeview expanding nodes upwards

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Is there anyway to subclass a Winforms Treeview to display root node ascendants expanding nodes upwards?
The following photoshopped image illustrates the desired result:

[image: Standard and reverse Winforms TreeView controls]

Comment: You can create such UI in WPF (With nodes at bottom). Take a look at [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b7fe9a1a-c8c6-45fb-a2bf-42233b20fe41/treeview-upside-down).

Comment: Thanks Reza but I need to use it on traditional Winforms projects

Comment: You can host a WPF control in Windows Forms, using an [`ElementHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?view=netframework-4.7.2) control. You can see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51662516/3110834) which shows you to create a Windows Forms user control which hosts a WPF control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you can rely on an [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) Windows Forms control to host a WPF `TreeView` control in it. Then for the WPF `TreeView` and its nodes, set `RotateTransform` to 180 degrees.

**Example**

In the following example I've created a Windows Forms `UserControl` containing an `ElementHost` to host a WPF `TreeView` control and by setting a 180 degree `RotateTransform` for the tree and its nodes, I'm making an upside down (a bottom up) tree:

[image]

Here is the code. Just add the code as a class in your application and make sure you have already added required assemblies which are mentioned at the end of the post. Then build the project and drop an instance of `MyTreeView` on your form.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Media;
public class MyTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl, ISupportInitialize
{
    private ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost();
    private TreeView tree;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TreeView winFormsTree;
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        tree = new TreeView();
        winFormsTree = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
        Nodes = winFormsTree.Nodes;
        tree.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(180);
        tree.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
        elementHost.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        elementHost.Name = "elementHost";
        elementHost.Child = tree;
        Controls.Add(elementHost);
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection Nodes { get; }
    public void BeginInit() { }
    public void RefreshTree()
    {
        tree.Items.Clear();
        RefreshTree(tree.Items, Nodes);
    }
    private void RefreshTree(ItemCollection items, 
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            var item = new TreeViewItem();
            var label = new Label();
            label.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(180);
            label.Content = node.Text;
            label.Padding = new Thickness(0);
            item.Header = label;
            items.Add(item);
            RefreshTree(item.Items, node.Nodes);
        }
    }
    public void EndInit()
    {
        RefreshTree();
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && winFormsTree != null)
            winFormsTree.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

*Referenced Assemblies*

Here are required referenced assemblies: `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework`, `WindowsBase`, `WindowsFormsIntegration`.

*Note*

For this example, I used a `TreeNodeCollection`. You can use any other structure which you like. You can add nodes in design mode using the `Nodes` property and see the tree at run-time. As a known issue for this example, the changed that you make in `Nodes` property will not reflect immediately at design-time, but are serialized and will be shown at run-time.